# Omitir los [] y "" con el uso de expresiones regulares Python

Tags: python, regex

```
def logs():
    with open("C:/Users/mfers/OneDrive/Escritorio/DataSciencePython/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
    pattern = r"""
    (?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
    (.*-\s )
    (?P<user_name>\w*)
    (.*\s )
    (?P<time>\[(.+?)\])
    (.*\s )
    (?P<request>\"(.+?)\")
    """
    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
        print(item.groupdict())
```

Ese es el código que llevo el me devuelve una lista de los host, user_name, time y request super bien pero en el time que es para extraer un texto que se encuentra entre: [(.+?)] este lo extrae pero no omite los corchetes y al igual que este con las comillas "(.+?)"

Comment: No se entiende nada.

Comment: Por favor explicate mejor, y ejemplifica todo

Comment: debes incluir un ejemplo minimo verificable. los datos de entrada,el codigo que llevas hasta ahora "que as intentado" y cual es el resultado deseado....

Comment: pattern = r"""(?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
    (.*-\s )
    (?P<user_name>\w*)
    (.*\s )
    (?P<time>\[(.+?)\])
    (.*\s )
    #(?P<request>\"(.+?)\")
       """
    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
        print(item.groupdict())

Comment: {'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'time': '[21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700]', 'request': '"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"'}

Comment: ves que el time esta con [] y el request con ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente haz que el grupo con nombre sea el interno en vez del externo. Me explico, en la expresión:

```
(?P<time>\[(.+?)\])
```

tienes en realidad dos grupos de captura. El "externo" al que has dado el nombre `time` captura todo, incluyendo los corchetes y lo que hay dentro de ellos. Pero dentro de los corchetes tienes otro grupo de captura "anónimo", el cual no te aparecerá en los resultados de `groupdict()`. Sin embargo, si lo hubieras escrito así:

```
(\[(?P<time>.+?)\])
```

Entonces el grupo externo es el anónimo (y de hecho no haría falta ese grupo), y el que capturas en cambio con el nombre `time` se refiere a lo que hay *dentro* de los corchetes, sin ellos.

Un ejemplo completo:

```
pattern = r"""
  (?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
  (.*-\s )
  (?P<user_name>\w*)
  (.*\s )
  \[(?P<time>.+?)\]
  (.*\s )
  \"(?P<request>.+?)\"
"""

logdata = "192.168.1.12 - foobar [12:23] \"blabklasfklaskl\""
for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

Imprime al ejecutarse:

```
{'host': '192.168.1.12', 'user_name': 'foobar', 'time': '12:23', 'request': 'blabklasfklaskl'}
```

Que creo que es lo que estabas buscando.

Comment: Sii super bien funciona miiiiiiil graciaaaaaas